# Optimize input image with class prior

Tags: optimization, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to implement the first part of the google blog entry 
[Inceptionism: Going Deeper into Neural Networks](https://research.googleblog.com/2015/06/inceptionism-going-deeper-into-neural.html) in TensorFlow. So far I have found several resources that either explain it in [natural language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856606/google-inceptionism-obtain-images-by-class) or focus on [other parts or give code snippets for other frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30994563/google-deep-dream-art-how-to-pick-a-layer-in-a-neural-network-and-enhance-it). I understand the idea of optimizing a random input image with respect to a class prior and also the maths behind it given in the this [paper, section 2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6034v2.pdf), but I'm not able to implement it myself using TensorFlow.

From [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39856291/how-to-visualize-dnns-dependent-of-the-output-class-in-tensorflow/39858096?noredirect=1#comment67705644_39858096) and the helpful comment by **etarion**, I now know that you can give a list of variables to the optimizer, while all other variables are untouched. However, when giving the optimizer a random image as a variable leads to

```
File "mnist_test.py", line 101, in main
    optimizer2 = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(-cost, var_list=[rnd_img])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 198, in minimize
  name=name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 309, in apply_gradients
  (converted_grads_and_vars,))
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ((None,<tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x7feac1870410>),)
```

For testing purpose I used a stripped down MNIST example. I tried to keep it as short as possible while still being readable and executable:

```
def main():
    # parameters
    learning_rate = 0.001
    train_batches = 1000
    batch_size = 128
    display_step = 50

    # net parameters
    n_input = 784 #28x28
    n_classes = 10
    keep_prob = 0.75

    weights = {
        'wc1': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, 1, 32])),
        'wc2': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, 32, 64])),
        'wd1': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([7*7*64, 1024])),
        'out': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1024, n_classes]))
    }

    biases = {
        'bc1': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[32])),
        'bc2': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[64])),
        'bd1': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[1024])),
        'out': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[n_classes]))
    }

    # tf inputs
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input])
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes])
    dropout = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

    # create net
    net = create_net(x, weights, biases, keep_prob)

    # define loss
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(net, y))

    # define optimizer
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

    # evaluation
    pred_correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(net, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(pred_correct, tf.float32))

    print "loading mnist data"
    from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    for i in xrange(train_batches):
        batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)

        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y, dropout: keep_prob})

        if i % display_step == 0:
            loss, acc = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y, dropout: 1.0})
            print "batch: %i, loss: %.5f, accuracy: %.5f" % (i, loss, acc)

    acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels, dropout: 1.0})
    print "test accuracy: %.5f" % (acc)

    # ====== this is where the reconstruction begins =====

    rnd_img = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, n_input]))
    one_hot = np.zeros(10)
    one_hot[4] = 1;

    # the next line causes the error
    optimizer2 = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(-cost, var_list=[rnd_img])

    for i in xrange(1000):
        session.run(optimizer2, feed_dict={x: rnd_img, y: one_hot, dropout: 1.0})

    sess.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The helper functions I used:

```
def create_net(x, weights, biases, dropout):
    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])

    conv1 = conv2d_relu(x, weights['wc1'], biases['bc1'])
    conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1, 2)

    conv2 = conv2d_relu(conv1, weights['wc2'], biases['bc2'])
    conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2, 2)

    fc1 = fullyconnected_relu(conv2, weights['wd1'], biases['bd1'])
    fc1 = tf.nn.dropout(fc1, dropout)

    out = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['out']), biases['out'])

    return out

def conv2d_relu(x, W, b, stride=1):
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, stride, stride, 1], padding='SAME')
    conv = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, b)
    return tf.nn.relu(conv)

def maxpool2d(x, k=2, stride=2, padding='VALID'):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, k, k, 1], strides=[1, stride, stride, 1], padding=padding)

def fullyconnected_relu(x, W, b):
    fc = tf.reshape(x, [-1, W.get_shape().as_list()[0]])
    fc = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc, W), b)
    fc = tf.nn.relu(fc)
```

I've found some sources saying that this error occurs when there is no path within the computation graph between the output and the variables to be optimize, but I don't see why this should be the case here.

My questions are:

1. Why isn't the optimizer able to apply any gradients?
2. Is this the right way to go in order to implement the visualization of a class?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Here is the complete code again, after incorporation of the accepted answer (for anyone who is interested). Anyway, the results are still not as expected, as the script basically produces random images after 100000 rounds of reconstruction. Ideas are welcome.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import skimage.io

def conv2d_relu(x, W, b, stride=1):
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, stride, stride, 1], padding='SAME')
    conv = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, b)
    return tf.nn.relu(conv)

def maxpool2d(x, k=2, stride=2, padding='VALID'):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, k, k, 1], strides=[1, stride, stride, 1], padding=padding)

def fullyconnected_relu(x, W, b):
    fc = tf.reshape(x, [-1, W.get_shape().as_list()[0]])
    fc = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc, W), b)
    fc = tf.nn.relu(fc)

    return fc;

def create_net(x, weights, biases, dropout):
    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])

    conv1 = conv2d_relu(x, weights['wc1'], biases['bc1'])
    conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1, 2)

    conv2 = conv2d_relu(conv1, weights['wc2'], biases['bc2'])
    conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2, 2)

    fc1 = fullyconnected_relu(conv2, weights['wd1'], biases['bd1'])
    fc1 = tf.nn.dropout(fc1, dropout)

    out = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['out']), biases['out'])

    return out

def save_image(img_data, name):
    img = img_data.reshape(28,28)

    mi = np.min(img)
    ma = np.max(img)

    img = (img-mi)/(ma-mi)
    skimage.io.imsave(name, img)

def main():
    # parameters
    learning_rate = 0.001
    train_batches = 1000
    batch_size = 100
    display_step = 50

    # net parameters
    n_input = 784 #28x28
    n_classes = 10
    keep_prob = 0.75

    weights = {
        'wc1': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, 1, 32])),
        'wc2': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, 32, 64])),
        'wd1': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([7*7*64, 1024])),
        'out': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1024, n_classes]))
    }

    biases = {
        'bc1': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[32])),
        'bc2': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[64])),
        'bd1': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[1024])),
        'out': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[n_classes]))
    }

    # tf inputs
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input])
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes])
    dropout = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

    # create net
    net = create_net(x, weights, biases, dropout)

    # define loss
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(net, y))

    # define optimizer
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

    # evaluation
    pred_correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(net, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(pred_correct, tf.float32))

    print "loading mnist data"
    from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

    sess = tf.Session()

    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    for i in xrange(train_batches):
        batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)

        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y, dropout: keep_prob})

        if i % display_step == 0:
            loss, acc = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y, dropout: 1.0})
            print "batch: %i, loss: %.5f, accuracy: %.5f" % (i, loss, acc)

    acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels, dropout: 1.0})
    print "test accuracy: %.5f" % (acc)

    # reconstruction part
    rnd_img = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, n_input]))

    one_hot = np.zeros((1, 10))
    one_hot[0,1] = 1;

    net2 = create_net(rnd_img, weights, biases, dropout)
    cost2 = -tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(net2, y))
    optimizer2 = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost2, var_list=[rnd_img])

    init_var_list = []

    for var in tf.all_variables():
        if(not tf.is_variable_initialized(var).eval(session=sess)):
            init_var_list.append(var)

    sess.run(tf.initialize_variables(init_var_list))

    save_image(rnd_img.eval(sess), "bevor.tiff")

    for i in xrange(100000):
        _, loss = sess.run([optimizer2, cost2], feed_dict={y: one_hot, dropout: 1.0})
        if(i%10000 == 0):
            cur_img = rnd_img.eval(session=sess)
            print "loss:", loss, "mi:", np.min(cur_img), "ma:", np.max(cur_img)

    save_image(rnd_img.eval(sess), "after.tiff")

    sess.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Some explanation: After rebuilding the graph with the new input variable and optimizer, I had to initialize the new variables, i.e. the rnd_img and some helper variables used by the Adam optimizer, hence the loop over all_variables() and checking for initialization status. If somebody knows a more elegant way, let me know. Or maybe that's the reason why I don't get any results?

Comment: How do you visualize activations for this code. I saw your earlier post which brought me to this code. I have a similar code structure using Tensorflow. could you please let me know how to visualize activations for each layer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rnd_img needs to part of the graph that you optimize. In your case, you just create a variable and tell the optimizer to optimize it, but the variable is not connected to the loss in the graph. What you can for example do is use another call to create_net with rnd_image instead of x (but using the same weights!), create the cost for that and then create a minimization op for that cost. Then for optimization you only feed in y.

Comment: That was it, thanks. Everything runs fine now, but unfortunately not as expected, i.e. even after 100000 of reconstruction I basically get still a random image, slightly modified. Is 100000 round not enough? I will update my question and add the modified code.

Comment: I just realized that maybe the fact that I omitted L2 normalization on the input image in the cost function might cause the problem. And I also thought about the sentence in the paper that says that they minimize the unnormalized class score, rather than the class posterior. So will try using something like cost2 = -tf.reduce_mean(tf.mul(net2, y)) + tf.nn.l2_loss(rnd_img). Does this meake sense, right?